# Future inside MaterialPageRoute builder returns null

Tags: flutter

Need to query server for an object before pushing the ProfileWidget route.

Not sure if error message has anything to do with the Future call inside the MaterialPageRoute's builder (see routes function)?

***ERROR***

> flutter: Another exception was thrown: The builder for route "null" returned null.

```
..
       @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return new MaterialApp(
              onGenerateRoute: routes,
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              theme: new ThemeData(
                  primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
                  textTheme: TextTheme(

                  )
              ),
              home: ...,
            )
            ;
          }

          Route routes(RouteSettings settings) {
            if (settings.name.startsWith("/profile")) {
              String username = settings.name.replaceFirst("/profile/", '');
              return MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    api.fetchProfile(username)
                        .then((profile) {
                      return ProfileWidget(profile);
                    });
                  }

              );
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly where the issue is. Async methods don't work properly within a build function as the build function is expecting a widget to be returned right away - by using a future you're actually just returning null.

Another issue is that you're calling your api in the build function - think about it this way... the build function is called any time anything is changed in your widget. Do you really want to fetch the profile every time that happens?

Instead, I'd recommend using a [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and starting the future in initState, or starting the future in initState and using setState(() ...) after completion. Either way, if you do it this way you'll have to deal with the case where there's a brief period of time before the profile is created, unless you think about doing something like moving the profile loading out of the widget into the main function (I don't know if that's really recommended but it seems to work for me).

You might even think about putting the profile into an InheritedWidget or ScopedModel so that if you change the logged-in user it propagates automatically.